# Yii url rewriting removing index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii, url-rewriting

I am trying to make the url rewriting and i want to remove index.php and I have done some research and found the online documentation aswell.

Here is what i did so far i uncomnted my main.php urlmaneger and i have the following

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScripName'=>false,
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
```

and i have .htaccess which is loacted in my yiiApplication

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Now when I launch the application it gives me the following error.

```
**Property "CUrlManager.showScripName" is not defined.**
```

How do I fix this?I do have my Rewrite engine on and also i have no errors on my php log or wamp server log.

Should I rewrite all of my urls inside of my project?

Comment: showScriptName instead of showScripName

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename to `showScriptName`, because you mistyped property name.

It should be:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Yep thank you worked perfectly. Ill mark is answered as soon SO lets me.